# Why is making salt water prohibited on Shabbat?

Tags: passover-seder-hagada, melacha-creative-work

I have read in a few hagadot, and I think in the OU Pesach guide that the salt water to be used for the seder must be prepared before Shabbat begins. That implied that there is some prohibition for doing this during Shabbat.

What melacha is being performed? Is there a prohibition of dissolving salt in water on Shabbat? Is there some other prohibition that we are concerned with?

Comment: "But when Pesach falls on Shabbos, the making of salt water presents a problem as set forth in Simon 321 in the laws of Shabbos." http://www.kollelmenachem.com.au/salt-water-on-shabbos.html  https://www.shemayisrael.com/parsha/ostroff/archives/shabbos74.htm  https://www.ou.org/torah/halacha/halacha-lmaaseh/shabbat-f-food-preparation-part-2/

Comment: Hi @rosends Please extract / translate relevant parts and make it an answer, when you can.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Shabbat 108](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shabbat.108a.13?lang=Bi) forbids making a large amount of salt water on *shabbat*.

[Rashi ad loc.](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Rashi_on_Shabbat.108b.1.2?lang=Bi) explains that the prohibition is because it looks like one is going to be tanning hides, one of the *avot melachot*. This explanation is echoed by [Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim 321:2](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.321.2?lang=Bi).

[Rambam Hilchot Shabbat 22:10](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Sabbath.22.10?lang=Bi) gives a different reason, namely that it gives the appearance of cooking.